# Evaluating $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{f(x_0 + \frac {1}{x})}{f(x_0 - \frac {1}{x})}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried many ways to think about a solution to the following question, but nothing works.

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{f(x_0 + \frac {1}{x})}{f(x_0 - \frac {1}{x})}\right)^x$$

$f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>0$

Comment: Hint: try taking $\ln$ on this function.

Comment: I tryed but then still I did l'hopital and it didn't work..

Comment: Did you get to this: $\frac{\ln{f(x_0+\frac{1}{x})}-\ln{f(x_0-\frac{1}{x})}}{1/x}$? It does not need l'Hopital then.

Comment: hmm, it is 0 / 0 why doesn't it need?

Comment: Think about the definition of derivative then: $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Would that help you? What is $f$ and what is $h$ here?

Comment: the definition of the derivative is  $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ and the problem is that $f(x_0)$ is a constant, and $\ln{f(x_0-\frac{1}{x})}$ contains $x$

Comment: Sorry for the typo. So $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ is the definition. But in your problem, the $1/x$ can be treated as the $h$, which goes to $0$. In fact, you can use the alternative definition by Timbuc's answer.

Comment: I didn't know his definition, how would you suggest continuing in your way?

Comment: That definition is derived from the original definition. So that was my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For any function $\;g\;$ differentiable at $\;x_0\;$ , you have that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x_0+h)-g(x_0-h)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)}h+\lim_{-h\to 0}\frac{g(x_0+(-h))-g(x_0)}{-h}=2g'(x_0)$$